# How to configure font style based on outside parameters

Tags: c#, fonts

I want to change the style of the font of a control based on input from the user or from saved data on database.
I tried many ways to construct the new font in one sentence but I couldn't.

Finally I ended up writing this code

```
        FontStyle fs = button1.Font.Style;

        if (Bold.Checked == true)
            fs |= FontStyle.Bold;
        else
            fs &= ~FontStyle.Bold;
        if (Underline.Checked == true)
            fs |= FontStyle.Underline;
        else
            fs &= ~FontStyle.Underline;
        if (Italic.Checked == true)
            fs |= FontStyle.Italic;
        else
            fs &= ~FontStyle.Italic;
        if (Strikeout.Checked == true)
            fs |= FontStyle.Strikeout;
        else
            fs &= ~FontStyle.Strikeout;

        button1.Font = new Font("Tahoma", (float)27.75, fs);
```

I want to know is there a smart way to construct the font style?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Don't start with the existing `FontStyle`, 
but with a `Regular` or one property (It's `Bold` in my example, but you can use any property as the first one, of course), and simply conditionally add properties:

```
var fs = (Bold.Checked) ? FontStyle.Bold : FontStyle.Regular;
fs |= (Underline.Checked) ? FontStyle.Underline : FontStyle.Regular;
fs |= (Italic.Checked) ? FontStyle.Italic : FontStyle.Regular;
fs |= (Strikeout.Checked) ? FontStyle.Strikeout : FontStyle.Regular;

button1.Font = new Font("Tahoma", (float)27.75, fs);
```